# How to pick the color code of image of taping area in windows 8 c#

Tags: windows-8

I am making project in windows 8 in which I want to pick the color code of image wherever i tap in that image.

I have done this in windows 7 but that classes are not supported in the windows 8 so they are giving the errors.

So plz help me to pick the color code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to find the position of taping area,
after that you will able to get the pixel of that area,
you can try..

```
Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(image1);
int x = Convert.ToInt32(clickPoint.X);
int y = Convert.ToInt32(clickPoint.Y);
```